# Unusual behavior of text inputs on stock Android browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, android, android-browser

*Edit*: Tested on **Droid X** running **Android version 2.2.1**. Samsung Galaxy S version unknown.

I'm developing a webpage designed to run on mobile devices, specifically Android and iOS. Everything seems to be working fine on iOS, but I'm experiencing very weird behavior on Android. I'm using ASP.NET with C# and jQuery.

Specifically, I have a form with several text inputs. There's nothing special about these text inputs:

```
<div class="line">
    <input name="street" type="text" id="street"
        style="height:25px;width:194px;" />
</div>
```

Now, when viewed on Android devices (specifically Droid X) the screen jumps erratically when inputting information. On a Samsung Galaxy S, the user isn't able to input data because the keyboard never appears when the text area is tapped. Any ideas?

Unfortunately, I cannot share a link as external requests are blocked by our firewall.

Comment: Do you have anything dynamic and still updating on that page?  This can sometimes cause the android browser to restart text input.  Try putting the field on a simple static web page for testing and see if you see the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the page is fully loaded when input is attempted. The same form seems to work fine on a very basic page (no CSS or JavaScript). The only JavaScript on the page adds touchstart and touchend event listeners to separate images on the page.

Comment: Well, usual advice is to eliminate differences between working and non-working version one by one until you find the culprit, then try to understand why and gripe to vendor / devise a work around as best as possible...  Do you absolutely have to have the touch listeners if they turn out to be at fault?

Comment: No, the touch listeners aren't required. I'm fairly certain I've tested without them, but I'll go back and try again. Assuming that doesn't fix the issue, are you aware of anything that would cause the page to jump around? More importantly, for the keyboard to not display at all?

Comment: All I can really say is what I already have - narrow down the differences between the working test and the non-working 'real' versions.  In particular, try to make a test via commenting out some pieces in whatever is generating the real version.